# Int array empty - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp, strcpy

I am attempting to write a program that will take two sets of strings N and Q. The goal of the program is to print out the number of times each string in Q occurs in N. However, I am struggling to manage strings and pointers in C and in particular I believe my issue stems from attempting to have an array of strings. I get a segmentation fault when the code below is executed. I have commented out my attempts at debugging using printf(). I believe the issue occurs when I try to assign S into the N_array.

```
int main() {
    int N, Q; 
    char *N_array[1000], *Q_array[1000];

    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int N_i = 0; N_i < N; N_i++) {
        //printf("made it through A for loop %d times\n", N_i+1);
        scanf("%s", N_array[N_i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &Q);

    //Does the array contain any information?
    //for (int N_i = 0; N_i < N; N_i++) { printf("N_array[%d] == %d\n", N_i, N_array[N_i]);}

    for (int Q_i = 0; Q_i < Q; Q_i++) {
        //printf("Made it to B for loop\n");
        int occurs = 0, result;
        char s[21];
        scanf("%s", &s[21]);
        strcpy(Q_array[Q_i], s);
        for (int N_i2 = 0; N_i2 < N; N_i2++) {
            //printf("Made it to C for loop\n");
            result = strcmp(Q_array[Q_i], N_array[N_i2]);
            if (result == 0) occurs++;
        }
        printf("%d", occurs);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remember that scanf won't read past a blank character in the string.  also if you use scanf on a 20 character buffer then you should use scanf("%19s", ... ) so that you don't overflow the buffer.  It is safer to use fgets (not gets) to read a whole line at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One problem is here

```
for (int N_i = 0; N_i < N; N_i++) {
    //printf("made it through A for loop %d times\n", N_i+1);
    scanf("%s", N_array[N_i]);
}
```

N_Array contains 1000 pointers to char, but each of those pointers points to, well.. nowhere. It's an uninitialized pointer which points to a random memory location you don't own. This is undefined behavior. You have to allocate memory before `scanf`.

```
 N_Array[N_i] = malloc(max_length_of_string + 1);
```

Another problem is this line

```
 char s[21];
 scanf("%s", &s[21]);
```

The second parameter of scanf should be just `s`, not `&s[21]`, which is just outside your array.

And one line below you have the same problem as described in my first point

```
strcpy(Q_array[Q_i], s);
```

`Q_array[Q_i]` doesn't yet point to any memory which you're allowed to write to. You should allocate memory here as well.

Comment: Note: "second parameter of scanf should be just s" implies `scanf("%s", s);`.  This is just about as good as `gets(s)`.

Answer (score 3):

1. `scanf("%s", N_array[N_i]);`

   This should lead to `SegFault` as expected as `N_array[N_i]` doesn't contain a valid memory address.

   What you need is to allocate memory using `malloc`, `calloc` to point `N_array[N_i]` to a valid memory location.

Correct code would be:

```
for (int N_i = 0; N_i < N; N_i++)
{
    if(!(N_array[N_i] = malloc((MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char))))
    {
        printf("malloc failed!\n);
        exit(1);
    } 
    scanf("%s", N_array[N_i]);
}
```

---

2. `scanf("%s", &s[21]);`

   This is incorrect as `%s` expects `char *` but type of `&s[21]` is `char **`.

   You need to use `scanf("%20s", s);` instead.

   This way `scanf` only read at most `20` chars (as we have `char s[21]`. So leaving last byte for `\0` character) and thus this will avoid accidental buffer overrun (where the length of string entered by user is greater than 20).

---

3. `strcpy(Q_array[Q_i], s);`

   Again here `Q_array[Q_i]` points to invalid memory address as it contains garbage value. Use `malloc`, `calloc` etc. to allocate memory first.

Correct code could be:

```
if(!(Q_array[Q_i] = malloc((MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1) * sizeof(char))))
{
    printf("malloc failed!\n);
    exit(1);
}
strcpy(Q_array[Q_i], s);
```